# Can cap-off red wire leaving switch box and red wire at ceiling fan box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

Many similar questions to "capping the red wire," but this seems different (and involves bypassing the old switch entirely).  I'm replacing an old ceiling fan (discrete motor & light switches) with "remote-system" fan (Ground, Neutral, Load wires only) [Ceiling-Fan Switch Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77FfB.jpg). The Ground and Neutral wires are untouched (still connected) in the switch box (all "Romex").  I connected the Source Load directly to the Hot (blk) wire going to the ceiling box.  I capped/wrapped the Red leaving the switch box.  I capped/wrapped the Red exiting at the ceiling box.

When I turn on the breaker and check the wires, Black is Hot **and** Red is Hot.  Is that scenario OK to leave if capped-off well?  The Red would be Hot if still attached to the switch (as I tested before disconnecting).

Adjacent to this box, is another switch box with old CresFlex wires (I think).  Both boxes are powerless when the breaker is off.  However, they do not interfere with each other's functions when active.  ***Second Box***: Doorway-to-wall-outlet by head of bed and probably for reading light...  I bypassed the switch on this by connecting the Pigtail with the Red wire (works fine). [image: Wall Outlet Switch by doorway]

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What are you testing the wires for electricity with?

Comment: I don't see any capped, unused wires (of any color) in the picture you provided. Would you please provide pics of the boxes in question.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel;  I tested with a basic noob voltage tester (Fluke 1AC II Non-Contact...): 'cuz I'm a noob at this stuff....

Comment: FreeMan;  I only posted my baseline pics.  I can send more later.

Answer (score 1):

You can cap the wire even if hot.
This is not uncommon where the fan was to run all the time or controlled by its pull chain and the lights by the switch.
Yes it is fine to cap a live wire in this case you may use it later for a different type of remote, the wire is not abandoned but for future use.
This is code compliant.

From what I see the red is switched and the black hot all the time but it won’t matter if fed from the fixture , or switch.

The only issue is a light switch is required at entry to most rooms. It could be to a receptacle or a fixture.